# find words in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

you know when you click on control-F to find word and then when you click on find all it gives you a list of all the cells that have that word

how can we put that in a formula so that it would list those results in a sheet 
so say i have this sheet 1

```
    A     |     B  
1 apple
```

in sheet 2

```
    A     |     B  
1 apple cider
2 peas
3 cucumber
4 apple
5 apple rum
6 carrots
7 beans
8 carrots and apples
```

i would like it the result to come out

```
    A       |      B       |     C       |    D 
1 apple        apple cider   apple rum    carrots and apples
```

Answer (score 1):

try to type this in formula bar:

```
FIND(expression, text_value)
```

and also go through this link:

```
http://www.smartsheet.com/help-categories/formulas
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I have tried that one before posting the question but didnt work or maybe i have not understood how it works

Comment: on nothing. was it of any help?

Answer (score 1):

Write this function in a module:

```
Public Function WordFinder(searchRange As Range, seekWord As String, iteration As Integer)
    Dim rangeCell As Range      'holder cell used in For-Each loop
    Dim rangeText As String     'holder for rangeCell's text
    Dim counter As Integer

    counter = 0
    'loop through cells in the range
    For Each rangeCell In searchRange.Cells
        rangeText = rangeCell.Value 'capture the current cell value
        'check if the seek word appears in the current cell
        If InStr(rangeText, seekWord) > 0 Then
            counter = counter + 1 'increment the occurrence counter
            If counter = iteration Then 'this is the occurrence we're looking for
                'return it
                WordFinder = rangeText
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rangeCell
    WordFinder = "n/a" 'that occurrence number was not found

End Function
```

And across the top row of your results sheet, enter this formula in each cell:

```
=wordfinder(Sheet2!$A1:$A8,"apple",column())
```

`column()` increments with each column, so as you copy/paste it across the top row, it's counting up.  The dollar signs make sure the reference remains absolutely on column A.

The 2nd parameter ("apple") can come from a cell, although I've hard-coded it here.

There might be a more elegant way to do this, but this is a quick & dirty way that should work.

Comment: thanks for your reply I have tried that but i need to play around with it more

Comment: Can you explain what that means? Also, if it works for you, it'd be great if you could approve the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To serach use [Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```
    expression.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
```

Example:

```
     Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I have tried that  but didnt work or maybe i have not understood how it works

Answer (score 0):

I've had to lookup the values manually .